# Como exportar banco de dados?

Tags: java, android

Preciso exportar meu banco para um arquivo texto. Já vi algumas perguntas do tipo por aqui, mas nenhum com uma resposta coesa ou coerente.

Segue trecho do meu código:

```
//ACAO DO BOTAO CADASTRAR
public void Cadastrar (View view) {

    //SALVO OS DADOS NO BANCO
    SQLiteDatabase db = banco.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("nome", nome.getText().toString());
    values.put("telefone", telefone.getText().toString());
    values.put("email", email.getText().toString());
    values.put("empresa", email.getText().toString());
    values.put("obs", obs.getText().toString());

    long resultado = db.insert("tab_clientes", null, values);


    try {


        //AQUI SERIA A PARTE DE EXPORTAR, MAS REALMENTE NÃO FAÇO IDEIA DE COMO FAZER
        FileOutputStream ArqTexto = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Clientes.csv");

        Cursor cursor = db.query("tab_clientes", new String[]{"_id_cliente", "nome", "telefone", "email", "empresa", "obs"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                cliente = new HashMap<String, String>();
                cliente.put("_id_cliente", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id_cliente")));
                cliente.put("nome", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
                cliente.put("telefone", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("telefone")));
                cliente.put("email", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
                cliente.put("empresa", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("empresa")));
                cliente.put("obs", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("obs")));

              }
              while (cursor.moveToNext()); 

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    if (resultado != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cliente Cadastrado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao Cadastrar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fledson, você poderia usar a mesma instância do `SQLiteDatabase` e executar essa query, retornando um `Cursor` onde basta iterar sobre as linhas e montar seu CSV. Para executar a consulta você pode tanto usar o método `query`, quanto o `rawQuery`, ambos lhe retornam um `Cursor`.

Comment: Grande @Wakim pesquisei sobre oq vc me sugeriu e cheguei nesse resultado. Atualizei o codigo. Ao compilar nao apresenta erro. Vc acha q esta correto? Agora eu nao sei como escrever no arquivo texto. Sei crialo atravez do: FileOutputStream ArqTexto = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Clientes.csv"); mas qual é a variavel onde se encontram os conteudos do banco? E como escreve-los?